# Calculating evolution of a wavefunction in a 3-dimensional infinite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

For a particle in a 3 dimensional infinite well, we can obtain a set of energy eigenfunctions separable in x,y,z,t as-
$$\phi_{lmn}(x,y,z,t)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{b}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{c}} \sin\left(\frac{l\pi x}{a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{m\pi y}{b}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi z}{c}\right)e^{-iEt/\hbar}$$

Now I don't understand how these solutions like that of the 1-dimensional infinite well are complete. I don't understand how if I have the initial wavefunction in the well as $$\psi(x,y,z,0)=Ne^{-\left(x^2+y^2 z^2\right)} $$ or any arbitrary wavefunction at $t=0$, how can I calculate the expansion coefficients so as to express it in terms of the separable solutions and calculate its evolution in time?

Comment: You need to express this function in terms of the energy eigenfunctions. It’s essentially a Fourier series.

Comment: I have the energy eigenfunctions. But how would I do the expansion? Because there are three sines here.

Comment: The three are independent. The x dependence of your arbitrary wavefunction can only come from the series in x. And so on.

Comment: So, you mean to say that I should assume completeness and using fourier's trick, calculate $c_{lmn}=(\psi,\phi_{lmn})$ inner product where $c_{lmn}$ are expansion coefficients?

Comment: Yup. That’s it.

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial wavefunction is not admissible here. The infinite well imposes the boundary condition $\psi = 0$ at $x \in \{0, a\}$, $y \in \{0, b\}$ and $z \in \{0, c\}$. All admissible wavefunctions can be decomposed as usual,
$$ |\psi\rangle = \sum_{lmn} \langle \Phi_{lmn} | \psi \rangle\, | \Phi_{lmn}\rangle . $$

This decomposition is similar to a Fourier series. In order to understand why this set of functions is complete, we should first understand why it works in 1D, where every function $\psi(x)$ with $\psi(0) = \psi(a) = 0$ can be written as
$$ \psi(x) = \sum_l C_l \sin(l\pi x/a) . \tag{*} $$
Proof: continue $\psi$ to an odd function on the interval $[-a,a]$ by setting $\psi(-a) = -\psi(a)$, then (*) is the regular Fourier sine series.

This result can easily be generalized to the 3D situation by successively applying the Fourier series to each coordinate separately.